# Is ntohl in x86 assembly necessary?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86, endianness

My goal is to send a integer value over TCP as little endian bytes to a client on windows, the client is written in x86 assembly.

If I were to send `htonl()` encoded bytes to the client would it be necessary being the client is compiled as x86? For instance wouldn't it be redundant to call `ntohl()` within my client's assembly code?

My overarching question is do I need to call `htonl()` server-side and `ntohl()` client side (x86 windows client)? Or should I just let the server do the work by checking if the server's architecture is big endian and if so swap the integer bytes via `__builtin_bswap32()` and send the little endian bytes to the client? I'm asking because I've read x86 is always little endian so it seems redundant if I know the client is always going to be written in x86 assembly.

Comment: What data you send is up to you to decide. So yeah, you can choose little endian if you like.

Comment: Yea if the server is big endian I don't want to send big endian bytes to create a bug in the x86 assembly windows client. If that makes sense?

Comment: Just ensure endianness in your protocol, that's all.

Comment: So you mean always ensure little endian bytes are sent to the x86 windows client? @Cheatah Just for clarity.

Comment: The first sentence says “My goal is to send a integer value over TCP as little endian bytes.” To accomplish that goal, you must send the bytes in little endian order. If you can do that by calling `htonl`, it satisfies the goal. If you can do that without calling `htonl`, it satisfies the goal. So it is not clear what you are asking. To send the bytes the way you want, send the bytes the way you want. If your goal is just to get the value across, and it does not need to be little endian, then send them any way you want. Just be clear about what the protocol is, then write code to implement it.

Comment: So receiving little endian bytes on the x86 client without calling `nothl` is fine? That's what I'm really asking, I just don't know if I need `ntohl `or not being the client ix x86.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Your comment is true but possibly confusing.  "Network" byte order is big-endian, as is x86's native endianness, so it's unlikely that `htonl` could be a useful part of sending in LE.  If you already had big-endian data on x86 (unlikely), `htonl` would be the semantically wrong name for a function.  You'd use `ntohl` to convert from "network" (big-endian) to "host" (little-endian) and send the result over the network.  Of course the transform is symmetric, just x86 asm `bswap` or `movbe`, because host endian is just the reverse of network, not something weirder.

Comment: @PeterCordes: My point is OP has not asked a clear question. They have said their **goal** is to send the bytes as little-endian and then have asked whether it is fine to send and to receive the bytes in little-endian order. Maybe their first sentence is phrased badly and their goal is not to send the bytes in little-endian order in the TCP transmission but to end up with bytes in little-endian order on the client. If so, they need to rephrase. If not, they still need to clarify. The question needs to be edited to be clear. It should be voted to close until that is done.

Comment: the keyword here is [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization): you put data on the line some way, and you read it back the same way. It doesn't matter you follow network order or not. You can also find more information in the [tag:serialization] tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My overarching question is do I need to call htonl() server-side and ntohl() client side (x86 windows client)?

No, that would convert to big-endian ("network" byte order), but you said you wanted to send data over the network in little-endian format.  On x86, that already is the `h` ("host") order.

In x86 asm, your data in memory will already be little-endian integers / floats unless you did something unusual (like using `bswap`, `movbe`, or `pshufb`, or byte-at-a-time shift / store.)

To be compatible with that in C, use `le32toh` (on receive) and `htole32` (before send) from [GCC's / BSD `<endian.h>`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htole32) instead of `ntohl` / `htonl`.  i.e. use LE as your network format instead of the traditional BE.

> call ntohl() within my client's assembly code?

That would be insane.  If you did want that, just use the [`bswap`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bswap) or [`movbe`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movbe) instructions instead of actually setting up args for a function call.  Normally those functions inline when you use them in C, although there is a stand-alone definition of `ntohl` in libc.

Also, no, you wouldn't want to do that.  Your client doesn't want to have anything to do with big-endian, which is what those traditional functions call "network" byte order.

x86 asm with AVX2 `vpshufb` can byte-swap at memcpy speed (including on small buffers that fit in L1d cache), but it's even more efficient not to have to swap at all as part of the first step that reads the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `htonl` function converts a 32 bit value from [h]ost byte order to [n]etwork byte order.  Host byte order may be either big endian or little endian, and network byte order is big endian.  The `ntohl` function does the reverse.

The purpose of these functions is to abstract away any possible conversion of the host's byte order and to have a known format for the network.  So on a little endian system these functions reverse the byte order, while on a big endian system they return the original value unchanged.

I would recommend using the standard network byte order, i.e. big endian, for sending values over the network.  They your code would use `htonl` to prepare values for sending and `ntohl` to read received values regardless of the host architecture.

Comment: If you're already writing in x86 (and/or ARM) assembly, I'd seriously consider using little-endian over the wire, because that's the native endianness for x86 and all(?) modern ARM / AArch64 systems.  You can abstract away little-endian in GNU C just as easily with [GCC's `endian.h`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htole32) for `le32toh` and `htole32`.

Comment: So in other words for the sake of simplicity sending little endian bytes over the network will do (when the receiving end is compiled x86 assembly)?

Comment: @uwu_2seko: Re “So in other words for the sake of simplicity sending little endian bytes over the network will do (when the receiving end is compiled x86 assembly)?”: You have asked this same question in several forms. The answer is simple: You can send the bytes any way you want. There is no law of physics, no rule of logic, no statute of government that says you have to do it one way or another. Just make a decision, document it clearly so it is known, and write the code. That is your answer.

Comment: So it won't lead to bugs then? Regardless of endianess?

Comment: @uwu_2seko: Not if you write bug-free code.  Sending LE over the wire is something that some protocols already do, and as everyone keeps telling you, there's nothing stopping you from doing it.  Just do it.  (Correctly and portably, ideally)

Comment: Thanks  I learned a lot today, sorry I wanted to be clear in understanding.